# Odd Deformation With Weight Paint

Tags: weight-painting

Here is my model in normal state. No deformations.
[image]

The second I rotate at this point we get this deformation. No other part of my mesh has this problem.
[image]

Here is the same mesh but backwards.
[image]

Here is the weight paint. It's mirrored on the other side.
[image]

And the geometry if it will help.
[image]

It looks as if something is stuck there and is causing this problem. looked around the problem area and I can't find any out of place geometry. Any ideas?

Link to the .blend file.
http://pasteall.org/blend/32923

Comment: mind uploading your .blend to http://pasteall.org/blend

Comment: Just uploaded it. Added link to post.

Comment: I'm not seeing the issues that your photos are showing. The worst thing I see is that part of the mesh isn't correctly attached to the bone

Comment: That might be the problem. How so? How it's painted?

Comment: When rotating `ribcage.002` I get some funny issues with the hair on the back of the head. Going into `Weight Paint` and `Wireframe` shading and looking out the back of the head from the inside I add some influence. This got rid of the issue for me.

Comment: @BlendingJake: Thank you for the help! Got my problem fixed and fixed what you found. Apparently, ribcage.002 and ribcage.003 had weight paints that were conflicting with one another too much. When rotating ribcage.003, the indent came from ribcage.002 having too much control of that area under the chin.